# Apply str_replace on parts of a string that do NOT match

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing form post data from a reply to a "thread" on my website and i am using Prism to add sytaxing to code

now here is my issue:

I am using php to echo the post contents into a div,yet due to how divs work `\r\n` isnt behaving as a newline, but rather `<br>` does.

but the prism script **DOES** use `\r\n` to represent a newline due to what it can contain (html code with 
 in it etc)

so basically i need to parse all the code that is NOT between

```
[CODE] and [/CODE] semi bb code
```

and change all the \r\n to 
`<br>` there

so a post response like this:

```
hello \r\n
im showing some code /r/n
[CODE=HTML]
<html> \r\n
\r\n
</html>
[/CODE]\r\n
thanks
```

into:

```
hello <br>
im showing some code <br>
[CODE=HTML]
<html> \r\n
\r\n
</html>
[/CODE]<br>
thanks
```

currently im using php to replace ALL `\r\n` into `<br>` but that breaks prism obviously

```
$cleancontent = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $cleancontent);
```

how can i use a regex expression (or any other solution) to find everything that is NOT between
"[CODE" and "[/CODE]" and replace `\r\n` into `<br>`

Comment: if you set the parent html element's css to have `white-space: pre-wrap` it would treat newlines as breaks without having to modify the source data.

Comment: thats a nice solution, but my source code has alot of whitespace in it and i think a programmatic solution would be much more pleasant to work with. thank you for the suggestion tho - i did not know that exists

Comment: but why not set the parent element to `pre-wrap` and then on whatever the `[code]` element generates overwrite that with the default `white-space: normal`

Comment: i told you i have whitespace in my code, and that it would be much easier to manage with the replacing solution. do you know how i can achieve what im looking for WITHOUT using css? thank you - i need code that can do such things in general,the fact that in this very place css can fix it is cool but i need a general solution to the replacement of string between non matching patterns

Comment: IMO, the easiest way would be to use a multi-part approach. replace all occurrences of the target string with something unlikely to appear in the source string like a call to [uniqid](http://www.php.net/uniqid). Then replace all occurrences of that unique string inside of `[CODE]` tags with the original target string. Then replace all remaining instances of the unique string with the new string. IMO, any single regex answer will get complicated fast. If you need an example of the above, let me know and I'll write a simple function if I have time.

Comment: im not sure i 100% understand your suggestion. just thought of something,is it not possible to create an object **INSIDE** the string pointing to some parts of it and applying functions only to it? i would love an example of what you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was suggesting.

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/bSODv7

```
<?php
class preg_replace_except_code {
    protected static $uniq;
    protected static $pattern;

    protected static function replaceCB($matches){
        return preg_replace("/".self::$uniq."/", '', $matches[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces all instances of $pattern found in $haystack with $replace except where $pattern is between [CODE] tags.
     * @param  string $haystack The string to search for instances of $pattern
     * @param  string $pattern   The string to find within $haystack
     * @param  string $replace  The replacement value
     * @return string           $haystack with all instances of $pattern replaced with $replace where not between [CODE] tags
     */
    public static function go($haystack, $pattern, $replace){
        //generate a uniq string that shouldn't exist in the haystack
        self::$uniq = uniqid('UNIQ_', true);
        self::$pattern = $pattern;

        //replace all occurrences of the needle with the unique string
        $haystack = preg_replace($pattern, self::$uniq.'$0', $haystack);

        //replace all instances of the unique string between [code] tags with the original string $pattern
        $haystack = preg_replace_callback("/\[CODE[^\]]*\].*?\[\/CODE\]/is", array('preg_replace_except_code', 'replaceCB'), $haystack);

        //replace all remaining unique strings, which should be only those outside [code] tags with the replacement string
        $haystack = str_replace(self::$uniq, $replace, $haystack);

        //return the original string with the correct replacements
        return $haystack;

    }
}

$haystack =<<<POST
hello
im showing some code
[CODE=HTML]
<html>

</html>
[/CODE]
thanks
POST;

$pattern = "/\r\n|\r|\n/";
$replace= "<br>";

echo '<h1>Before replace:</h1>';
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($haystack).'</pre>';
echo '<hr>';
echo '<h1>After replace:</h1>';
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities(preg_replace_except_code::go($haystack, $pattern, $replace)).'</pre>';
```

Comment: thanks alot , i will study the code and tell you how it went. very appreciated

Comment: i am getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION" i think its you calling function() and i do not know why. im running  php 5.2.17

Comment: You are using an old version of php, I'll fix to work backwards. Give me 2 minutes

Comment: try that. [I tested to work on all php version 5.0+](https://3v4l.org/a7c3F). I had to wrap the function in a class and so it is called similar, but a little different: `str_replace_except_code::go($haystack, $needle, $replace)`. This was because I needed to pass some functions to the old anonymous function that was throwing an error and I didn't want to just make them global. The difference is the `::go` part after what was the function name.

Comment: i think your code works now! thanks alot - by the way $needle = "\r\n"; is the right way to type it. my original post was wrong!

Comment: here: http://altpalace.com/code/thread.php?id=1 if you want to see your code in action :)

Comment: I assumed it was wrong, but it served the point to easier see the replacements. Also, should probably trim() the text inside the `[code]` blocks. I see a newline at the top of each code block which I'm assuming is from the newline after `[code]`. Leading and trailing newlines are not really important. perhaps just a `trim($code, "\r\n");` which will only remove leading/trailing newlines.

Comment: tried some things myself too,cant seem to be able to detect and delete the newline created by the user creating a newline (ironic) and deleting it for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: not all newlines are `\r\n`. Windows is typically `\r\n`, mac is `\r` and linux is just `\n`. I'll correct it to use preg_replace and show you what pattern to use.

Comment: updated, also I renamed it to preg_replace... because it now takes a pattern, not a normal string like str_replace does.

Comment: updated. So I ran into an issue. It doesn't actually replace the newlines anymore, but it adds a `<br>` before each newline outside of the code tag. For newlines that should be fine. Anything else, you would want to use the older code likely. If that doesn't work for you, let me know. I have another way it could be done but don't have time right now to rewrite this. I can do it tomorrow.

Comment: im still using the old code,besides the the newline on the code everything is ok. its actually **not your codes fault** its actually what should happen when you type a tag and newline immoderately after it.